# Set of $n$ numbers which has no two elements whose sum is an another

Tags: combinatorics

I want a set $S = \{ S_1, ..., S_n \} $ of $n$ numbers, which satisfies the condition $S_i + S_j ∉ S$, where $i, j = 1 ... n$. How could I compute a solution set for it? In other words, the set must satisfy that the sum any two elements is not an element of the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be any integer at least 2. Then for any *nonzero* $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ let $S = \{mk + \ell; k = 1,2,\ldots, n\}$.

Taking powers of $m$ would work too.

Answer (score 6):

Take any set of odd numbers.

$\hspace{0pt}$

Answer (score 3):

Take any sequence $S_1, S_2, \ldots$ such that $S_1 > 0$ and $S_n > 2 S_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set $$\{1,3,9,...,3^{n-1}\}$$